# Inversive distance between concentric circles

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, transformation, mobius-inversion

I found an explication about Inversive distance in Coxeter book. But, i don't really understand some things in its explication.
I can't imagine the meaning of:

> *''This inquiry almost forces us to invent, for any two non-intersecting circles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, an inversive distance ($\alpha$, $\beta$) such that, if $\gamma$ belongs to the non-intersecting pencil $\alpha\beta$ and if $\beta$ lies between $\alpha$ and $\gamma$, then*
> $(\alpha, \beta) + (\beta, \gamma) = (\alpha, \gamma)$".

Then it says:

> *"Inverting in a circle whose center is one of the limiting points, we
> obtain three concentric circles."*

I do not understand the meaning of "circle whose center is one of the limiting points".

Here is an image of that page.[image]

[image]

Here is what i get but only 2 concentric circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two circles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with radical axis $l$, the pencil $\alpha\beta$ is the set of circles $\gamma$ which share this radical axis, i.e. the radical axis of $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ is $l$ as well (and thus automatically also the radical axis of $\gamma$ and $\beta$). In the picture below, the pencil is drawn in solid lines (black), and the common axis is the vertical (grey) line.

If and only if the circles do *not* intersect, there exists a circle (dashed red in the picture), which is centered at the intersection of $l$ and the common axis of symmetry $g$ of the pencil, and orthogonal to all circles of the pencil. This circle intersects the axis of symmetry in the two **limiting points** of the pencil. These can be thought to be the two circles of zero radius belonging to the pencil.

Inverting in a circle (dotted blue in the picture) centered at one of those points will leave the axis of symmetry invariant. The dashed circle, however, becomes a line orthogonal to $g$, since it passes through the center of inversion. A circle belonging to the pencil will be transformed to another circle orthogonal to both lines, which is thus necessarily centered at their intersection. Therefore, the pencil is transformed into a pencil of concentric circles, all centered at the intersection of $g$ and the image of the dashed circle.

Since the radius of the circle of inversion is arbitrary, and choosing another radius corresponds to scaling the inverted picture, any well-defined quantity derived from the inverted picture has to be invariant under scaling. Therefore, it has to be defined as an expression of the ratios of the concentric circles - which is exactly what Coxeter proceeds to do. He defines $(\alpha, \beta)$ - the "distance" of the two circles - to be the logarithm of the ratios of the radii of the inverted circles.

[image: A pencil of coaxial circles]

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but how is it possible that your circle of inversion has the same center as 2 inversed circles ? I don't really understand how we get 3 concentric circles but not only 2. I added an image of what i get in my question. Thank you! @Josef E. Greilhuber

Comment: @Daniil I don't really see the problem. Draw any third circle of the coaxial pencil, invert it, and you will get a third concentric circle in your picture. The circle of inversion is *not* concentric with the circles of the pencil, it just really looks like that in my picture (I hope I didn't make a mistake drawing it). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that what i meant. But, on your picture the circle of inversion(as i understood it;s a blue one)has the same center as inversed circles

Comment: @Daniil Oh yes, I might have accidentally drawn the second smallest circle of the pencil with the wrong center (they are awfully close together). I will correct it as soon as I am at a reasonable computer.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: And i also don't really understand how Coxeter finds that the logarithm (of base $e$) of the rations of the radii of the inverted circles give the result as a distance between 2 concentric circles . I mean that there's no proof of that.

Comment: This is a definition, not a proof. That it's base $e$ doesn't really matter, you could use any other base (just as you could measure distances in feet instead of metres). Importantly, while $(\alpha,\beta)$ is called the "inversive distance" of circles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, it really is *not* the euclidean distance, since it is scale-invariant! It just behaves like a distance function of two objects "should" behave, in that it satisfies the triangle inequality, with equality if and only if the three circles are in a nice configuration (the pencil in this case).

Comment: Okey, i see what you mean. But if it isn't euclidean distance, how can this definition help us to construct the chain of Steiner using this ''inversive distance''? @ Josef E. Greilhuber

Comment: It does not help us in itself, the theorem rather goes like this: If and only if $(\alpha,\beta) = a_n$ (for a particular number sequence $a_n$), we can construct a Steiner chain with $n$ circles. The reason being that, after inverting into two concentric circles with $e^{a_n}$ as their radius, these admit a Steiner chain (consisting of $n$ congruent circles, of course). One can just invert this chain again to obtain a chain for the original pair.